# Auto and Inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11

Pseudo code

```
class Animal
class Cat : Animal (Inheritance)

array<Animal> Animals;
Cat MyCat = new Cat();
Animals.Add(MyCat);

auto TargetAnimal = Animals[0];
```

would auto be deduce to Cat or to Animal?

Comment: `Animal`. You can verify by `typeid(decltype(TargetAnimal)).name()`. Also you should never ever ever do this. Look for `Object Slicing`

Comment: Thanks! Just double check - Slicing aint a problem in my case, everything is pointer in our framework :)

Comment: Also, what is `array` ? It is for sure not std::array, right ? And you must publicly inherit for inheritance to work . And you are adding a `pointer` to array whereas its expecting a value. In short the code pasted is completely wrong.

Comment: aka Pseudocode, i'm working with UDK 3 which is all pointer with custom arrays/list

Comment: what the hell is `array`?